# Custom properties not shown in search results, but in profiles shown

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, user-profile-property, display-template

Im connect custom attributes in profile service AD item (homePhone, CellPhone), after sync they are shown in profiles (private sites). Then Im add this properties in display templates of search results and add it in type of results - nothing in search results. I doing some tests, my parameters in display templates gets null. Why its working in private sites, but in search results not?

In search result, its seems like:

> Peter Petigru
>
> Work phone: 1000
>
> Mobile Phone:
>
> Home Phone:

All 3 attributes in 1 display template, configuring correctly. How you can see work phone correctly shown, because hes default in profile service.

Comment: Im try to debug results page and found this:
My items "undefined" http://puu.sh/jYwG4/0c083d947c.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im resolve my problem.
Steps:
1. Delete search index
2. in Search Schema delete default lines with needed parameters
3. Create our own lines with needed parameters
4. Run full crawl

All works. And i still dont understand why thats not work with default lines, they was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create Managed Properties for the Custom User Profile properties? Search and Display Templates use Managed Properties on the context of the current item.

I have a complete walk through of the steps if you have never done this before: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/

Comment: Display template how in your instruction.

>Did you create Managed Properties for the Custom User Profile properties?

If you mean sync settings in profile service - thats ok. Because private sites gets custom properties information.

>Search and Display Templates use Managed Properties on the context of the current item.

What you mean? in search service -> Search Schema? Thats, I think ok 
http://puu.sh/jZylJ/4025713cec.png

Comment: Yes, you always have to create your own Managed Properties in the Search SSA for User Profile Properties.

Comment: But thats not help... in search still blank

Comment: @PavelKolbasov did you work through the whole post? Did you create the managed properties in the SSA? (It does not work in the Site or Site Collection with User Profile Properties.) Did you perform a full crawl after creating the Managed Properties? This always works.